# Edit and Continue will not work when modifying a comment

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using VS 2012 Express on Windows 8.  Recently I tried enabling E&C and it worked somewhat then I made some configuration changes that were prompted, and I wasn't paying much attention to what they were, and now, when modifying anything, even when modifying a comment in any part of the code, VS comes up with a reason why it can't E&C.

When I modify even a comment I get the message "Modifying a 'method' which contains a dynamic invocation will prevent the debug session from continuing while Edit and Continue is enabled."

Comment: Well, does the method contain a dynamic invocation?

Comment: Not every code change is supported.  MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx)

Comment: It seems as though no changes are allowed at all. I will begin researching this topic and see if I can find any instance of being allowed to edit and continue.