# Visual Studio 2012 Edit and Continue not working with dynamic

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, edit-and-continue

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

In my C# project, I have used a typed DataTable class, which uses the dynamic keyword in a few method implementations ([Handcrafted Strongly Typed ADO.net DataTable - Can it be cleaner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203915/handcrafted-strongly-typed-ado-net-datatable-can-it-be-cleaner)).

While debugging, I am not able to use the edit and continue feature. I get the error:

```
"Modifying a 'method' which contains a dynamic invocation will prevent the debug session from continuing while Edit and Continue is enabled."
```

I have read other similar threads, which mention to set EmbedInteropTypes to false in all referenced assemblies. But in my case, they are already set to false. I found this issue reported for VS2010 as well on the net; is it not fixed as of VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

Other members also got the same issue before using the VS2012:

[Edit and Continue will not work when modifying a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745072/edit-and-continue-will-not-work-when-modifying-a-comment)

And the E&C really has some default limitations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927(v=vs.110).aspx

I help you submit a feedback to the connect report team:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3104579/visual-studio-2012-edit-and-continue-not-working-with-dynamic

The product team will share us the latest information.